# Camera: Native Module 'CameraView' was null (react-native-camera-vision)

Tags: react-native, expo, camera-view, react-native-vision-camera

I'm running an EXPO project (https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/#installing-the-library)

I've ran

- expo install react-native-vision-camera
- added the plugin in my app.json (code below)
- expo prebuild

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-native-vision-camera",
      {
        "cameraPermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Camera.",

        // optionally, if you want to record audio:
        "enableMicrophonePermission": true,
        "microphonePermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Microphone."
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Still getting this issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpezF.png

EXPO SDK 46
react-native-vision-camera: 2.15.1

Read a bunch of docs saying react-native-vision-camera does not work with Expo - but there are setup docs with expo.  Not sure how to move forward from here. 

Thanks guys

I've tried running pod install in ios dir, installation was successful but no luck.
```

Comment: Does you get any solution @russian_cosmonaut